# taking input from user and search it in a text file and return the position of that point in the textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to search a string (which is input by the user) in a text file and if the string exist in the text file then it will return it's position (position in the file)

I am using seek and tell methods of text file in python

```
def search(self,identity):
    with open("dbase.txt", 'r') as dbase:
      find = dbase.readline()
      while str.casefold(find) == str.casefold(identity):
          pos = dbase.tell() 
          find = dbase.readline()
          return pos
```

complete code :

```
class app:
    ''' class that takes the data and save it
    into a text file name dbase.txt'''
    def get_data(self):
        self.name = input("Name : ")
        self.add = input("Address : ")
        self.mob = input("Mobile : ")
    def write_data(self):
        dbase = open("dbase.txt",'a')
        dbase.write(self.name+"\n")
        dbase.write(self.add+"\n")
        dbase.write(self.mob+"\n")
        dbase.close()
    def read_data(self,pos):
        dbase = open("dbase.txt",'r')
        dbase.seek(pos)
        self.name = dbase.readline()
        self.add = dbase.readline()
        self.mob = dbase.readline()  
        print(self.name)
        print(self.add)
        print(self.mob)
    def search(self,identity):
            data = open("dbase.txt", 'r').read()
            desired_string = identity
            if desired_string in data:
                pos = data.find(desired_string)
                return pos
            else:
                print("The desired string does not exist in the file")

call = app()
f = input("Enter :")
pos = call.search(f)
call.read_data(pos)
```

identity stands for the user input which I passed in this function as a parameter and I want to match this identity in the file and i am extracting file data in a variable find so if find is equals to identity then I want to return it's current position in file but it's not working, I had tried to print something in the while loop such as print("x") or something else to check weather the While Loop condition goes true or not because if it goes true then it will print that "x" but it does not print anything from which I concluded that the while loop condition goes false therefore I am thinking that the fault is in the line.

```
while str.casefold(find) == str.casefold(identity):
```

but I am not getting why is it so because the string which I input is actually existing in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = open("filename.ext", 'r').read().replace("\n", "\n\n")

desired_string = "apples"

if desired_string in data:
    index = data.find(desired_string)
else:
    print("The desired string does not exist in the file")
```

The above code will search for the desired string in the file, and if it exists the index of its first occurrence will be stored in the variable `index`. Otherwise *The desired string does not exist in the file* will be printed.

Comment: tell me one thing that if the string is "apples" exists in a file containing some data such as-- "banana orange grapes apples" and one more thing is that each fruit name is in new line then what will store in index if i search for apples then it will store 0 in index as if taking list of letters apples then 'a' is at 0 position of it will store the file position of apples in index as given by tell function

Comment: @KHANAYAAN If the file content is *"banana orange grapes apples"*, then index will store the value 21. Why? Because 21 is the index from where our string is matched. `index` variable will store the index of the first character from where our string has been matched.

Comment: still it does not gives the desired result i am print the 3 fruits names let us again consider the data is "banana orange grapes apples" i mean desired_string is orange then cursor must goes from 'o' of oranges to 's' of apples but it prints only orange grapes still apples is not printing

Comment: @KHANAYAAN I am unable to understand what are you trying to achieve with your above code. Do you want to print all the contents of the file, after the desired string is matched?

Comment: okay let me explain i actually want to save name address and mobile number of a person in a text file using the get_data() [used to take user input] and write_data() [used to write that in file dbase.txt] i hope this much is clear now coming to next thing now i want that the user must input his/her name to see his data so in the variable 'f' [see the last 3rd line] i takes the name of the user to search his/her name in the text file using the search() and in search i had passed his/her name that is the variable 'f' as a parameter which is accepted by the variable 'identity' in search()

Comment: so now coming to the search() we have identity variable in which the name(string which we will search in the text file) is available now we had loaded the full file data as a string in a variable 'data' in the search function  and now we are checking if desired_string(identity) in data then position is stored in pos using data.find(desired_string) and returned this pos, now we call the read data function and open that text file and placing the cursor at that position using dbase.seek(pos) and reading the data of that particular user and printing it

Comment: yes it's working fine Now. Thanks For This Can You Now Explain To me why "while str.casefold(find) == str.casefold(identity):" is not working here i used str.casefold() because may be in text file name of user is written as Alex(for example) and while searching it might be possible that he will input (alex) that's why i used str.casefold() so that Alex and alex both becomes same but it did not worked.

Comment: @KHANAYAAN Well, if all you want is caseless comparison, then you could try `string.lower()` or `string.upper()` which changes the case of every character in the string. `str.casefold` isn't the best way of doing caseless comparion, so I would suggest you to use something like `string.lower()`